# How to iterate over a XML file and sum a specific field

Tags: python

I want to iterate over an xml file and get the sum of the field "PremieTot" (marked in the xml below)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1" ?>
<Bericht Version="1.0" xmlns="http://www.test.nl/test/2022/01">
  <Bericht>
    <IdBer>1111</IdBer>
    <IdLcr>2323</IdLcr>
    <NmLcr>Test Company</NmLcr>
  </Bericht>
  <AdministratieveEenheid>
    <LhNr>3434</LhNr>
    <NmIP>Test Company</NmIP>
    <TvkCd>MND</TvkCd>
    <TijdvakAangifte>
      <DatAanvTv>2022-01-01</DatAanvTv>
      <DatEindTv>2022-01-31</DatEindTv>
      <VolledigeAangifte>
        <CollectieveAangifte>
          <TotaalRegelingen>
            <RelNrAansl>3434</RelNrAansl>
          </TotaalRegelingen>
          <TotaalRegelingen>
            <RelNrAansl>3434</RelNrAansl>
          </TotaalRegelingen>
        </CollectieveAangifte>
        <InkomstenverhoudingInitieel>
          <NumIV>1</NumIV>
          <DatAanv>2020-01-01</DatAanv>
          <PersNr>2364</PersNr>
          <RegelingGegevens>
            <PremieTot>0.52</PremieTot>        //I want to sum this field
          </RegelingGegevens>
        </InkomstenverhoudingInitieel>
        <InkomstenverhoudingInitieel>
          <NumIV>1</NumIV>
          <DatAanv>2020-07-01</DatAanv>
          <PersNr>2365</PersNr>
          <RegelingGegevens>
            <PremieTot>0.66</PremieTot>            //I want to sum this field
            <AantVerlUPens>29.12</AantVerlUPens>
          </RegelingGegevens>
        </InkomstenverhoudingInitieel>
      </VolledigeAangifte>
    </TijdvakAangifte>
  </AdministratieveEenheid>
</Bericht>
```

Iam trying it with xmldict to parse the xml file into a dict, but for some reason i cant get the value "PremieTot"

```
info_dict = xml_dict["PensioenAangifte"]["AdministratieveEenheid"]["TijdvakAangifte"]["VolledigeAangifte"]


premieTotal = [xml_data["RegelingGegevens]["PremieTot"] for xml_data in info_dict]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quite easy with [`ElementTree`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html):

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET

et = ET.fromstring(xml)

result = sum(
    float(el.text)
    for el in et.findall('.//{*}PremieTot')
)
```